# How to configure Windows Group Policy using c++?

Tags: c#, c++, wmi

I am working on IE BHO toolbar. When I install it for IE 8, it works fine. In case of IE 9, It pops up an info bar asking if to enable it. I know what settings to change in group policy manually. I just do not know how to do it in programming.

Changes to make are in Group Policy:

- Location: User Config

  - Administrative Template

    - Windows Components

      - IE

        - Security Features
          Add-on Management

Modifications:

- Set Add-on list to enabled
- Add an entry in Add-on list

Are there any straight forward APIs to do this job?

I am primarily looking for C++ APIs but I am fine with C# / WMI based approach too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exists a couple of ways to handle the Windows Group Policies

1) You can use  the [Group Policy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has a set of [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access from C++.

2) [Using the RSoP WMI Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082%28VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_group_policy_core_classes)

3) Locating the windows registry key where the Group Policy are stored using the [`Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server`](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250)

Comment: A nice detailed answer. Thanks.

Comment: Updating group policy from registry is not correct. It may work, but actual information is stored in `env:windir\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\registry.pol`. Based on this Windows updates registry keys. Updating registry may work only temporary.