# How to change SRP Security Level using commandline

Tags: batch-file, registry

Are you able to change service restriction policy security level using the command line or a batch/reg script

I'm unaware of how to do this within the registry

I'd like to have a BATCH/REG to change srp security level, any helpful information is appreciated

Comment: SRPs (that's _software_ restriction policies) are set through a group policy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/software-restriction-policies-technical-overview

Comment: So is there no way of doing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834069/how-to-change-group-policy-via-command-line

Comment: Is there no way of doing it through batch?

Comment: Not that I see. You might want to try asking on SuperUser since this question is more geared towards system administration.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax to change it using lgpo